# how to upload multiple images to server with multiple buttons

Tags: html, upload

I have 23 database image fields: `image1`, `image2`, ....etc.
I need in one page to add multiple upload buttons and when I click on each button the image saved on folder and its name on database and same for button `2` , `3` ....etc
Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: As I understand it, StackOverflow is about helping people solve specific coding problems that they have already tried to debug themselves, but are coming unstuck.  It is not about designing a whole system on your behalf.  Sorry, but we'd need to see your HTML, Javascript and back-end code before we can comment on any specific issue you may be having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin like ["jQuery File Upload"](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html).

Comment: to enable another instance of jquery file upload it said in manual to add    $('.fileupload').each(function () {
    $(this).fileupload({
        dropZone: $(this)
    });
});
but i don't know where exactly to add it

Comment: how to apply this please? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page i think this for old version

Comment: Why do you want to add this plugin several times? That would be easier for you and your user if you create one plugin and on your server side you get all images and can consider image1 as the first image, image2 as the second, etc...